# I'm editing a text in ten Word files. Each file has numbered sections, but I want to add numbers to each section that are continuous

Tags: microsoft-word

This is perhaps a text editing query rather than a Word query. Each file is divided into sections that are consecutively numbered following the file number: "1.103" is the number of the 103rd and last section in the first file. The stop only occurs in these section numberings. The first section in the second file is numbered "2.1", I can change that manually so that it reads "2.1 (104)", but I then want the consecutive numbering to continue incrementally through that second file, generating another cumulative number at the end for me to transfer to the first section in the third file, and so on up to the tenth file. Can anyone help with this? Gratefully, Karen

Comment: Do you want 2.104 or do you want 2.1(104) and, in either case, what is the next number in the series supposed to be? Take a look at http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Comment: I want "2.1 (104)". I realise that I shall have to do this one file at a time, supplying the new running total at the beginning of each file.

Comment: What should the numbering sequence be? What was the last number in the previous document? What should the first number in this sequence be? What should the next number be? When should the "2" that starts your numbering change to a "3"?

Comment: There are 10 files. The "2" changes to a "3" in the third file, up to a "10" which begins all the sections in the tenth file. The section numbering by the tenth file should begin with "10.1 (827)", the previous 9 files having contained a total of 826 sections. So I need a formula to enable me to input the total number of sections from the previous file, in the case of the second file "103", and add 1 to it for every occurrence of "." in the text, replacing for example "2.2" with "2.2 (105)", and so on. I shall have to begin again for all the subsequent files.

Comment: What changes 2.1 to 2.2?

Comment: Why separate documents? This makes a complex solution even more complex. Can the order of these change? I.e., can what is currently the third section change and become the second or fifth section?

Comment: What you want to do can be done. It may involve a combination of multilevel list numbering set up as described in this page: http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html and possibly use of the Sequence Field http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields Then we need to get the numbering from the previous chapter or section. Again, why separate documents?

Comment: The files all contain text (it's a large anthology), with the sections numbered, so "2.2" exists already.  This is not I imagine something to be resolved by Word itself but with a simple substitution formula that includes incremental counting. The documents are separate books, I could put them back together temporarily to execute the task if it would help, but it would be easy to run the formula ten times.

Answer (score 0):

### This is somewhat complex and will require discipline in use.

If all that is being changed are the parenthetical numbers, I would recommend using a [Sequence Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields) for those. This can be saved in AutoText. You would manually set the starting number at the start of each document.

If the Section numbers are also being automatically changed, you should set up a multilevel list following the methods set forth in Shawna Kelly's [page on numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). The parenthetical numbers would be a level in that multilevel list set to NOT restart when the levels above change.

Unless these change on a daily basis, I would recommend simply resetting the start-at numbers manually when needed. If they change on such a basis, macros or other fields can be used. Write down the process to do that so that it can be followed easily.

For [SEQ fields](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html), this would be done by using the /r "switch" in the field code to tell Word the starting number for each book. You can use INCLUDETEXT fields to pull starting numbers from prior documents. That number would have to be a bookmarked number in the prior document. That could be used in the first SEQ field.

### SEQ field example - first one in a book after the first book

This requires the name and exact computer path to the previous book. The last SEQ field in the document should be in a bookmark named "lastnumber."

```
{ SEQ paren /r { INCLUDETEXT "(full path)\Book 1.docx#lastnumber" }
```

### SEQ field example - all others

```
{ SEQ paren }
```

***Again, these fields can be stored as AutoText for easier insertion.***

For Multilevel lists, the starting numbers can be set in the Define New MultiLevel List dialog.

If possible, you want the styles in all of the documents to be the same.

### Field notes

1. Fields cannot simply be typed. You need Word to insert the special
   delimiter characters in pairs. They are not on the keyboard! See my notes: [Typing Fields in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#typefields).
2. Fields do not update automatically. You can update them by selecting all text and pressing the F9 key. On most systems, Print Preview will update fields. [Which fields update?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211629)

Comment: It sounds as if it will be easier to get the publisher to add the continuous numbers. Thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: You are welcome.